# Does this improper integral diverge?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

Let $N(t)$ be a counting function, $t>e$, such that $\liminf\limits_{t\to{+\infty}} {\frac{N(t)}{t\log t}}>0$. Why does the following integral diverge?
$$-\displaystyle\int_e^{+\infty} {\dfrac{N(t)}{t^2 \log^2 t} {\rm dt}}$$.

By assumption, we have $\liminf\limits_{t\to{+\infty}} {\frac{N(t)}{t\log t}}>0$, so exist $c>0$ and $c'$ such that $N(t)\ge ct\log t -c'$. But when I replaced it on the upper integrals, I only obtain that
$$ -\displaystyle\int_e^{+\infty} {\dfrac{N(t)}{t^2 \log^2 t} {\rm dt}} \le -c\displaystyle\int_e^{+\infty} {\dfrac{\rm dt}{t\log t}} + c'\displaystyle\int_e^{+\infty} {\dfrac{\rm dt}{t^2\log^2 t}}. $$
In there, $\int_e^{+\infty} {\frac{\rm dt}{t\log t}}=\log\left|\log t\right|\big|_e^{+\infty}=+\infty$ and $\int_e^{+\infty} {\frac{\rm dt}{t^2\log^2 t}}$ converges. How can I continue to prove the above integral diverges?

Comment: You have proved that the right-hand side of the second inequality diverges to $-\infty$. What can you say about the original integral (the left-hand side of the inequality)?

Answer (score 0):

As suggeste in the comments, you are probably done, since:
$$ -\displaystyle\int_e^{+\infty} {\dfrac{N(t)}{t^2 \log^2 t} {\rm dt}} \le -c\displaystyle\int_e^{+\infty} {\dfrac{\rm dt}{t.\log t}} + c'\displaystyle\int_e^{+\infty} {\dfrac{\rm dt}{t^2.\log^2 t}} = -\infty. $$